# Debian 8 Mlt 0.9.2-2 & Qt Creator 5

Tags: c++, video, debian, qt-creator, mlt

I'm using MLT Framework for a University project.
I upgraded my computer to QtCreator5 and since, I can't launch any MLT project.

When I launch this project https://github.com/mltframework/BuildOnMe created for Qt4, first I changed the all the `#include <Qt...>` names with the syntax of Qt5.

Then when I launch the project I have a segmentation fault. When I debug, it comes from the function `mlt_factory_init()`.

The problem is that I can't go back to Qt4 because I already use some important aspect of Qt5 to improve my project, also it's a school computer so I can't migrate to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I'm really stucked at this point.

I Tried this:

-> `mlt_factory_init()` is declared as taking a directory as parameter so I tried to put `mlt_factory_init("/tmp/BuildOnMe/")`. My application is launched but when I call any video source then I have the same error.

-> I had as piece of advice to create my own build with MLT 0.9 but I just don't know how to do it, I think I misunderstood that.

Ubuntu MLT is at the version 6.3 so there is no issues with Qt5, but I can't find anywhere the documentation for MLT 0.9.2-2 for my Debian 8.

-> I also tried to use the Testing packages of MLT of debian but when I try to `apt-get install` it with the proper syntax I have a lot of dependencies that may corrupt my distro (200 deleted package for 50 new installed) i'm not very confident with it.

If you have any idea I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your install of MLT includes the qt module/plugin built against Qt4, and it is not possible to use both Qt4 and Qt5 in the same process. You need to either stick with Qt4, make your own build of MLT against Qt5, or simply remove the installed libmltqt.so.